# add homeKit accessory error alert

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, homekit

i am trying to add accesrroy in home here is my code

```
    home.addAccessory(accessory, completionHandler: {[weak self]
            (error: NSError!) in

            let strongSelf = self!

            if error != nil{
                println("Failed to add the accessory to the home")
                println("Error = \(error)")
            } else {
                println("Successfully added the accessory to the home")
                println("Assigning the accessory to the room...")
                strongSelf.home.assignAccessory(accessory,
                    toRoom: strongSelf.room,
                    completionHandler: {(error: NSError!) in

                        if error != nil{
                            println("Failed to assign the accessory to the room")
                            println("Error = \(error)")
                        } else {
                            println("Successfully assigned the accessory to the room")

                            strongSelf.findServicesForAccessory(accessory)

                        }

                })
            }

        })
```

but it show me error

[image: aelrt]

and accessory couldn't be added in home.

```
  println("Failed to add the accessory to the home")
```

above mention statement does execute. it's not asking for accessory setup code.

Comment: What message do you get from `error`?

Comment: error msg:- Failed to add the accessory to the home
Error = Error Domain=HMErrorDomain Code=54 "Failed with OSStatus code -6722 (kTimeoutErr)" UserInfo=0x7f8438449080 {NSLocalizedDescription=Failed with OSStatus code -6722 (kTimeoutErr)}

Comment: this line is causing problem. "home.addAccessory(accessory, completionHandler: {[weak self]
            (error: NSError!) in"

Answer (score 2):

What you have explain is not quite helpful in finding the exact reason,I have faced the same error many times and error logs was not sufficient however i fixed it by following steps.

- **Reset the simulator or delete your application**
- **Run your application and try to add accessory again.**

As per my understanding this error only
        appears on simulator environment as you will run application on real device and test it with the real accessories instead of **Home Kit Accessory Simulator** this issue may not appear(Not Tested on device Yet).

I hope it may helpful to you.